# Why is $\mathbb{P}(f_{j+1}=m, f_i=l | f_0=k) \leq \mathbb{P}(f_{j+1}=m | f_0 =k)$?

Tags: markov-chains

Why is $\mathbb{P}(f_{j+1}=m, f_i=l | f_0=k) \leq \mathbb{P}(f_{j+1}=m | f_0 =k)$?

Where $i,j \geq 0$ and nothing is assumed by the order of probabilities.

And where $(f_i)_i$ is a Markov chain that's homogenous.

Comment: Monotony of measures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A\cap B|C)=\frac {P(A\cap B\cap C)} {P(C)}\leq \frac {P(A\cap C)} {P(C)}=P(A|C)$ always. Markov property is not required.

Comment: What's this called?

Comment: @mavavilj  No name. If one event is contained in another then the probability of the first is less than or equal to the probability of the second.

Comment: So you assume what kind of "contained in"? $A \subset B$?

Comment: Take $A=(f_{j+1}=m)B=(f_i=l), C=(f_{0}=k)$ and use the fact that $A\cap B \subset A$.

Comment: @mavavilj $(f_{j+1}=m,f_i=l)$ is the notation used for the intersection of teh events $(f_{j+1}=m)$ and $(f_i=l)$